# Kafka Connection to node -2 (host/A.B.C.D:9093) terminated during authentication

Tags: apache-kafka

Dears,

Kafka 2.6.0

I've strange problem. Application client cannot check status of transaction because of:

```
Connection to node -2 (kafka2/A.B.C.D:9093) terminated during authentication. 
This may happen due to any of the following reasons: 
(1) Authentication failed due to invalid credentials with brokers older than 1.0.0, 
(2) Firewall blocking Kafka TLS traffic (eg it may only allow HTTPS traffic), 
(3) Transient network issue.
```

but early the same application client pubslished some event without problems in the same topic:

```
2021.02.23 09:49:34.742 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] INFO  c.v.w.e.c.KafkaConfiguration$KafkaProducerListener - Event with key: d59ca6ba-111f-42ec-333c-995e3b059593 sent successfully to topic: test.single
```

Do you have any idea what can be wrong?

Best Regards,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were missing my CA root cert in file /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/java/cacerts
How to solve it:
copy your ca root certificate to /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
and run command:
update-ca-trust extract

Regards,
Dan

Comment: We also get the same warning after running the app for a while. But, app is running fine even after this warning. Any other issue with kafka client?

Comment: No, there is no other issue with kafka client.